# Looking for a word that means "to be gullible to your own ideas"

Tags: terminology

I thought the word i was looking for was "naive", but when i looked up the definition it didn't seem right. Is it right? Regardless, what are some words that define this?

Comment: Do you want a word that describes one who will believe the first explanation he formulates for an observation? I believe Isaac Asimov covers this (though I am not sure if he gives a word for it) at the start of *The New Intelligent Man's Guide to Science*, but I do not have that book on hand.

Comment: Something like this, but not limited to the first observation made.

Comment: I wish I knew! // Nice proverb on this topic though: "The way of a fool is right in his own eyes: but he that hearkeneth unto counsel is wise." _Proverbs 12:15_

Comment: sidenote: And a fascinating article re: why we all, at least to some extent, are resistant to changing our mind: [Why reason and evidence won’t change our minds](https://www.google.com/amp/www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/02/27/why-facts-dont-change-our-minds/)

Comment: Confirmation bias?

Comment: Are you asking about someone who appears to have ***drunk their own Kool-Aid***?

Comment: A dreamer, Ignorant, Self-assured, Over-confident, Zealot/zealous, Passionate. None of these are directly on the market but they all dance around it

Comment: "believe your own hype" is quite a common *phrase* in this area.

Answer (score 1):

**self-delusion**

> The action of deluding oneself; failure to recognize reality.
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self-delusion).

Comment: Prone to self-delusion?

Answer (score 0):

"**arrogant ignorance/ignoramus**"

Sorry - not a single-word term, but I think this covers your question perfectly.  This is what Sarah Silverman ascribes to her on-stage standup persona and what makes her so bitingly awesome!  A lot of people (still) just don't get it.